# How to display data in one table with 4 columns.Note: Two xsl:for-each statements are used

Tags: html, css, xslt

I could really use some help as I've been trying for over 2 weeks. So far, I can display 3 columns whose attributes are testName,duration & outcome. While the final attribute "storage" is appended to the generated table. How do you display all the attributes into one table with 4 columns (testName,duration,outcome & storage)?
Thanks in advance for any help.

**xsl:for-each select="/cruisecontrol/build/t:TestRun/t:Results/t:UnitTestResult"**

```
        <tr>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="@testName"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="@duration"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="@outcome"/>
          </td>                                       
           </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
```

**xsl:for-each select="/cruisecontrol/build/t:TestRun/t:TestDefinitions/t:UnitTest"**

```
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="@storage"/>
      </td>

    </tr>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Posting a chunk of <t:TestRun>...</t:TestRun> xml would help.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the actual XML (posting a sample of the TestRun portion of the document would be useful), you can try:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">

      <table>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="//build/Results/UnitTestResult"/>

      </table>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="//build/Results/UnitTestResult">

    <xsl:variable name="ParentPosition" select="position()" />

    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="$ParentPosition"/>
      </td>      
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="@testName"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="@duration"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="@outcome"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::Results/TestDefinitions/UnitTest[$ParentPosition]/@storage"/>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the use of position() and how it can be used as a variable in the <xsl:value-of select. Also note how you can use apply-templates to avoid xsl:for-each. This is cleaner as the top down approach keeps the correct position() in the hierarchy.

I've applied it to this XML (a well-formed version of the content you added earlier with the namespaces removed for simplicity - you may have to add them back in, although I didn't need to with the above stylesheet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<cruisecontrol project="RetailBuildAll">
  <request source="IntervalTrigger" buildCondition="ForceBuild">
    IntervalTrigger
    triggered a build (ForceBuild)
  </request>
  <modifications />
  <build date="2010-03-18 13:50:10" buildtime="00:52:57" error="true" buildcondition="ForceBuild">
    TestRun id="9dede87a-1e32-4796-a706-bd8c9484df6d"
    name="lx00551@ROCPWBUILDER41 2010-03-18 14:25:08"
    runUser="EKC1\lx00551"
    xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2006">>
    <Results>
      <UnitTestResult executionId="71197f46-0ce1-46bb-896c-94de56a8341d" testId="e0b1d5ad-1f54-e491-58ed-227d74752b17" testName="_AmountDueNotSet" computerName="ROCPWBUILDER41" duration="00:00:01.8571146" startTime="2010-03-18T14:25:13.1997766-04:00" endTime="2010-03-18T14:25:15.4653871-04:00" testType="13cdc9d9-ddb5-4fa4-a97d-d965ccfc6d4b" outcome="Passed" testListId="8c84fa94-04c1-424b-9868-57a2d4851a1d">
        <Output>
        </Output>
      </UnitTestResult>
      <UnitTestResult executionId="d23eb331-6f98-4d6e-b5ac-6cadf5cbc23e" testId="1284c514-fede-0eec-dca9-4a83d1df9eb0" testName="_AmountDueSet" computerName="ROCPWBUILDER41" duration="00:00:00.3020513" startTime="2010-03-18T14:25:15.4653871-04:00" endTime="2010-03-18T14:25:15.7778851-04:00" testType="13cdc9d9-ddb5-4fa4-a97d-d965ccfc6d4b" outcome="Passed" testListId="8c84fa94-04c1-424b-9868-57a2d4851a1d">
        <Output>
        </Output>
      </UnitTestResult>
      <TestDefinitions>
        <UnitTest name="SaveToArchiveItemThrowsExceptionWhenNotValid" storage="\retail\bin\DATA.retailplatform.imaging.imageobjectstest.dll" id="95af8a39-34e8-7b01-de6a-a647d9ee4053">
          <Css projectStructure="" iteration="" />
          <Owners>
            <Owner name="" />
          </Owners>
          <Execution id="700c3770-242a-4ee3-af98-110d2c31a1d7" />
          <TestMethod codeBase="x:/Retail/bin/DATA.RetailPlatform.Imaging.ImageObjectsTest.DLL" adapterTypeName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestAdapter, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.Adapter" className="DATA.RetailPlatform.Imaging.ImageObjects.LayeredImageTest, DATA.RetailPlatform.Imaging.ImageObjectsTest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" name="SaveToArchiveItemThrowsExceptionWhenNotValid"
           expectedException="DATA.RetailPlatform.ShoppingCart.Conversion.InvalidForSaveToArchiveItemException, DATA.RetailPlatform.ShoppingCart.Conversion, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
        </UnitTest>
        <UnitTest name="_RemoveEntryTitleMatchWhileNotUpgrading" storage="\retail\bin\softwaremanifesttest.dll" id="f0444c96-9751-23f2-2e5f-43114f036ed8">
          <Css projectStructure="" iteration="" />
          <Owners>
            <Owner name="" />
          </Owners>
          <Execution id="a1411bf5-8ee4-4e37-ba24-10398a325950" />
          <TestMethod codeBase="x:/Retail/bin/SoftwareManifestTest.DLL" adapterTypeName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestAdapter, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.Adapter" className="SoftwareManifestTest.SoftwareManifestManagerTest, SoftwareManifestTest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" name="_RemoveEntryTitleMatchWhileNotUpgrading" />
        </UnitTest>
      </TestDefinitions>
    </Results>
  </build>
</cruisecontrol>
```

Comment: My apologies if I didn't make myself clear. I left my laptop in the office. I'll supply xml data tomorrow. Thanks folks for replying. But yes, what you have is very close to what I'm looking for. NOTE: There are 4,000 "UnitTest" elements with the same name & at the same level. They also all have the same attribute name "storage". The value for each storage attribute is different. If I put in "[2]" "ancestor...UnitTest[2]/@storage" I will get the next/new storage value at the next/new element UnitTest.

Comment: If the attribute value is based on the position in the hierarchy, then you can also use the position() and number functions. I'll look out for your XML!

Comment: Okay, thanks dash and others. I've added a mini portion of the XML that I'm working on and a comment related to using the position() function. If I could create a counter within the UnitTest element, then I could extract each storage attribute. I just don't know how.

Comment: @jasonhodge I've updated the example. Give it a try and let me know.

Comment: Hey Dash...Thanks for the prompt response. I'll give it a go now.

Comment: First off thanks for being so generous in using your time to assist me. I really appreciate it. So I ran the stylesheet and nothing happened. No errors or anything. The file generated was 1KB w/ no data. Would you like me to email you the actual xml file I'm working against? I also tried editing the code you provided by placing in "t:" after the build/ (Otherwise you cannot enter the structure because it's Css. I would then have to include sl:stylesheet version="2.0" and xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" into the stylesheet. I'll play around in the AM with the code you provided.

Comment: Please let me know if you figure something out. Thanks again Dash!

Comment: Hey Dash, pastebin is not accepting it. Probably because its over 65,030 lines of XML code. And in order to use chat, I still have to build up criteria because I'm a new user. Here's my email Jason3206@yahoo.com. Perhaps you can message me and i'll send you the file. Sorry for the headache...